# Save and Update HTML form in iOS

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I need to save HTML form in document directory after editing some of its parts like textfield,dropdown value so that when a user opens HTML form in offline mode he can edit that form as per his need then can update the form as well.I am showing this HTML form on WKWebView.

**In short I need to save with all the filled fields.**

Code snippet to store HTML form:

```
//use this data to write to any path as documentdirectory path + filename.html
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //create file path
    NSString *htmlFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",RecordId] stringByAppendingFormat: @"%@", FormTitle]stringByAppendingFormat:@".html"]];
    //write at file path
    BOOL isSucess = [data writeToFile:htmlFilePath atomically:YES];
    if (isSucess)
        NSLog(@"written");
    else
        NSLog(@"not written");
```

I got stuck in this scenario.Please help